# Remove duplicates from string without additional buffer

Tags: java, strings

I completed an exercise from the *Cracking the Coding Interview*:

> Design an algorithm and write code to remove the duplicate characters in a string without using any additional buffer. NOTE: One or two additional variables are fine. An extra copy of the array is not.
>
> Follow-up: Write the test cases for this method.

I would like to ask whether my solution for the question is good enough, because the solution given in the book doesn't seem to work correctly.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class duplicateString{

    public static void rduplication(char [] word){
        if(word == null) return;
        int len = word.length;
        if(len<2) return;
        int count=0;
        for(int i =0;i<word.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<word.length;j++){
                if(word[i] == word[j]){
                    count = count + 1;
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
                if(word[i] == word[j] && count > 1){
                    word[j] =0;

                }

            }
            count = 0;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(word));  
    }

    public static void main(String []  args){
        String word = "ababab";
        rduplication(word.toCharArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Method Signature: your method should return a result, instead of printing it to increase reusability and (automatic) testability.
- Complexity: The complexity of your method is higher than it has to be. One simple improvement would be to start the second loop at `int j = i` to avoid duplicate checks.
- Performance/Duplication: You check `word[i] == word[j]` twice. Just move the `if (count > 1)` check inside the first `if` to avoid this duplication.
- Argument Checks: Just returning in case of an invalid argument (`null` in this case) is not a good idea; throw an exception instead to avoid possible bugs in the future.
- Argument Checks: Returning nothing in case of a word length of 1 or 0 seems like a bug. I would expect an empty array or an array with the one entry to be returned (ie `removeduplicate(['a'])` should equal `['a']`, not nothing).
- Result Value: Your array still contains entries in the positions where duplicate characters were (eg `aaaaab` -> `[a, , , , , b]`. This isn't what I would expect (also, the question talks about accepting a string, and presumably returning a string as well; it then also talks about arrays, so using an array internally - instead of eg `charAt` - is presumably correct, but I would still expect the input and output to be strings).
- `count = count + 1` can be written as `count++`.
- Naming: `removeDuplication` would be a lot clearer. `removeDuplicateCharacters` would be even more precise.
- Formatting: Your spacing is inconsistent, leading to less readable code.
- Declare variables as late as possible to increase readability. For example, `count` isn't needed until inside the first loop.

Taking this all together, you would get something like this:

```
public static String removeDuplicateCharacters(String word) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(word);

    char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();

    int len = wordArray.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < wordArray.length; j++) {
            if (wordArray[i] == wordArray[j]) {
                count++;
                if (count > 1) {
                    wordArray[j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return String.valueOf(wordArray);
}
```

It's a bit too nested for my taste, but otherwise I think it's mostly ok.

Comment: I'd like to add the class name which violates standard naming conventions.

Comment: @Marvin oh, true, class names should always start with an upper-case character. `DuplicateString` also doesn't seem ideal, as it doesn't contain a duplicate string (but that's probably not relevant for this exercise).